# SQL Function - how to add a DateFrom and DateTo (date range) parameter?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my main query, I am getting a cost per customer per date, like below:

```
10.00 - James - 01/01/2018
30.00 - John -  15/05/2018
```

So my date filters would be like below*:

```
where DATEcolumn >='01/01/2018'
and DATEcolumn   <='30/06/2018'
```

I then want a function to give me the sum of these costs, based on my date ranges. Result like below:

```
10.00 - James - 01/01/2018 - 40.00
30.00 - John -  15/05/2018 - 40.00
```

I know I could get this through a sub-query, but I need this through a function unfortunately as the application I'm using has limitations. What I'm asking for might not be possible but thought I'd ask. Thanks

*I made a mistake explaining the DATE columns, sorry. It's one date column, not two.

Answer (score 2):

Using an inline table valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnCostByRanges (
    @DateFrom DATE,
    @DateTo DATE)
RETURNS TABLE RETURN
    SELECT
        P.Price,
        P.Name,
        P.Date,
        TotalPrice = SUM(P.Price) OVER ()
    FROM
        Prices AS P
    WHERE
        P.Date BETWEEN @DateFrom AND @DateTo
```

You use it with:

```
SELECT
    P.*
FROM
    dbo.ufnCostByRanges ('2018-01-01', '2018-05-01') AS P
```

Comment: Damn, sorry, I made a mistake on my initial question. The date column in my query is one column. So the query would actually be:

where date >='01/01/2018'
and date  <='30/06/2018'

Comment: @PaulS i've edited the answer to use a BETWEEN against the only column Date.

Comment: I made an amendment to my question just before you made yours! I still think my issue remains after your adjustment. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when dateFrom >= '2018-01-01' and dateTo <= '2018-06-30'
                then costs else 0
           end)
from t;
```